# Geotechnical engineering: What does a negative Skempton's pore pressure parameter mean?

Tags: geotechnical-engineering, soil-mechanics

I am reading B.M. Das' book Principles of Geotechnical Engineering, 6th edn.

In the chapter about Consolidated-Undrained triaxial test it is mentioned that the range of Skempton's pore pressure parameter, $\overline{A}$, is -0.5 to 0 for overconsolidated clays.

My understanding is that $\overline{A}$ is the percentage of the extra axial stress that is resisted by the pore water pressure. The rest of the axial stress is handled by the effective stress i.e. the grain structure of the soil. So what does a negative $\overline{A}$ represent? Are there capillary forces that causes the effective stress to equal both these plus the total axial stress?